# IF statement in FOR loop not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am creating a batch file to initialize a portable game and run it locally on a computer for performance purposes, and another script to save the game to the portable drive when finished and check for updates.

**Batch File** (save, update, & clear local cache)

```
@echo off
title Minecraft - Save
echo [%date%^|%time%]
echo NOTICE: Initializing Minecraft ...
if exist %appdata%\.minecraft (
    :: Save World
    echo NOTICE: Directory "%appdata%\.minecraft" found.
    echo NOTICE: Saveing world files ...
    echo ^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^* [%date%^|%time%] ^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^* >> %cd%\logs\save.log
    echo Copying files ... >> logs\save.log
    xcopy /e /y %appdata%\.minecraft\saves %cd%\.minecraft\saves\ >> %cd%\logs\save.log
    echo Complete! >> %cd%\logs\save.log
    :: Get Updates
    echo NOTICE: Checking for updates ...
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set /a count=0
    for /d %%d in (%appdata%\.minecraft\versions\*) do (
        rem @echo !count! - %%d 
        if not !count!==0 (
            echo NOTICE: Downloading update (!count!) ...
            echo ^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^* [%date%^|%time%] ^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^* >> %cd%\logs\update.log
            echo Update found. Copying files... >> %cd%\logs\update.log
            xcopy /e /y %%d %cd%\.minecraft\versions\ >> %cd%\logs\update.log
            echo Complete! >> %cd%\logs\update.log
        )
        set /a count+=1
    )
    :: Clear Local Files
    echo NOTICE: Clearing file cache ...
    rd /s /q %appdata%\.minecraft
)
:: ERRORLEVEL
if not exist %appdata%\.minecraft (
    echo ERROR: Destination directory not found.
    echo NOTICE: Minecraft save unsuccessful!
    goto end
)
echo NOTICE: Minecraft save successful!
:end
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 10 -w 1 >> nul
exit
```

The `FOR` loop works fine but when I put an `IF` statement inside of the loop, the batch file quits unexpectedly.

Comment: might be caused by this line `echo NOTICE: Downloading update (!count!)`  - and closing bracket to be root cause - change it with curly or rectangular brackets

Comment: @npocmaka Thank you. The script works. If you post this comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might be caused by this line echo `NOTICE: Downloading update (!count!)` - and closing bracket to be root cause - as it is taken for closing of IF condition. Change it with curly or rectangular brackets

Comment: Or, if you do insist on `()` parentheses, escape those as follows: `echo ... ^(!count!^)`. IMHO only `)` _closing_ parenthesis needs to be escaped...